# Приведение типов и многое другое

Tags: codeblocks, c++

Всем привет. Помогите с кодом пожалуйста. Мне нужно сделать из int string. Я уже все способы перепробовал, везде пишет, что не найден оператор и т.п. Я новичок, поэтому туплю. Вроде бы stringstream сработал, но при компиляции вылезает ошибка bad alloc, это связано с переполнением памяти. Вот код:
pastebin.com/kZC44q5g

Спасибо

Comment: @newfag, Добавьте ваш код к вопросу в виде кода, а не изображения.

Comment: @newfag соблюдайте отступы и правила форматирования кода, вам же легче будет искать ошибки, и всегда делайте показ строк....

Answer (score 1):

[[@newfag](/users/25341/newfag)](/users/25341/newfag), выложите код хотя бы на pastebin.com или ideone.com. Чтобы дать точный ответ, было бы неплохо ваш код запустить и пройтись по нему отладчиком, но набирать вручную лень. Навскидку наиболее вероятная причина падения - вы длину строки определяете посредством `sizeof`. Это и с массивом `char`'ов не работает, не то что с классом `string`. Для определения дины строки, хранящейся в объекте класса `string`, используйте метод `size()`: `lng = str.size();`.

**UPD**

Вот ещё пара косяков:

1. При чтении из потока нескольких переменных нужно отделять их операторами `>>`, а не запятыми, как у вас: `myfileinput>>x,n;`.
2. Вы используете неинициализированные переменные `n2`, `temp`. Переменные нужно инициализировать перед использованием. Компилятор имеет право записать в неинициализированные переменные любой мусор.
3. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы объяснили, чего хотите добиться вашим кодом. В данный момент особого смысла я в нём не вижу. В частности, ошибка `bad alloc` у вас возникает из-за того, что вы бесконечно дописываете в `ss` какие-то строки. `stringstream` не очищается перед каждой записью, поэтому разростается до бесконечности и забивает собой всю память.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kZC44q5g прошу

Comment: @newfag, обновил ответ.

Comment: @fori1ton Спасибо тебе! Этот код для решения одной интересной задачи http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?chapterid=2796#1
Пойду исправляться

Comment: @newfag, как мир тесен, за "mccme" респектую)

Comment: Каждое следующее значение последовательности считает блоки однотипных цифр предыдущей строки и выводит вместо них пару из количества цифр и номинала цифр.

Т.е. 13112221 - одна единица (11) + одна тройка (13) + две единицы (21) + три двойки (32) + одна единица (11). Следующее значение будет 1113213211

Comment: http://ideone.com/nuVc29

а вот и решение =) Если не спортивно - смотрите, только когда сами решите.

Соответственно, число в строку я переводил `std::to_string(curnum);`, а вот строку в число переводить не пришлось.

Comment: @newfag: вот [решение, которое `string::find_first_not_of` использует](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af28fed537454c89).

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку до `-std=c++11` стандартной функции `to_string()` не было, то видимо более надежно писать код:

```
 #include <stdio.h>  // для sprintf
 ...
 char tmpbuf[21];    // максимальный размер long long целого со знаком и завершающим nil
 sprintf (buf, "%d", i);  // в данном случае i -- int (достаточно было бы буфера размером 12)
 string str(tmpbuf);
```

Comment: @avp: *"более надёжно"* использовать библиотеку вместо изобретения велосипеда. Существуют ли популярные платформы, где нет c++11 компилятора? (Даже на Винде можно использовать `to_string()`). Гарантировано ли, что `int` поместится в `tmpbuf[21]` (ecли мы о надёжности говорим)? (Я не видел, что `int` ограничен сверху в размере в С++ стандарте -- было время, когда `int` был 16 бит, сейчас обычно больше, завтра может быть 128 бит). Если не хочется `to_string()` использовать, то можно `stringstream` или `snprintf()/sizeof(int)` или `boost::lexical_cast`.

Comment: @jfs, про: 

    Существуют ли популярные платформы... ?

не то что бы в  

    avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ uname -a; g++ --version
    Linux avp-xub11 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28  13:31:23 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
    g++.real (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
    ...

нет c++11, просто лень `-std=gnu++11` все время набивать.

--

О гарантиях.  
100% гарантий никто не даст, но если говорить об `int`, то думаю, что останется он 32 бит (даже на 128 бит компах (которые, IMHO не за горами)). Так что 12 (21 это для 64 бит) байтной строчки вполне хватит.

Comment: @avp: Чтобы не набивать опции руками, можно один раз в Makefile написать: `CXX := g++ -std=c++11` (или то что на данной версии работает).

`int` уже может быть 64 бит на платформе с ILP64 моделью, даже short может быть 64 бита на SILP64 -- такие модели редки, но они существуют (существовали).

Основная идея в том, что лучше библиотечную функцию использовать вместо своих поделок (по-меньшей мере sizeof int, CHAR_BIT позволяют кол-во цифр найти), чтобы другие люди заботились о переносимости реализации, оптимизации скорости и исправлений багов (eg, `boost::lexical_cast` был медленный одно время)

Comment: @jfs, ну, с Makefile-то понятно.

Тут несколько другое. Как Вы думаете, сколько лет требуется, пока новое (в нашем случае C++11) не станет уже повсюду общепринятым?

Я вот помню, что в R&R C мы писали что-то вроде

     void f (a, b)
       int a;
       double b;
     {
        ...
   

вместо современной записи `void f (int a, double b) { ... }`, которая появилась еще в конце 80-х. 

А писали-то все равно по старому еще и в середине 90-х, поскольку где-нибудь обязательно найдется компайлер, который этих новшеств не знает.

То же и с крестами (а про буст я вообще молчу).

Comment: Про разные архитектуры.

Вы серьезно считает, что можно (и вообще стоит) стремиться к *абсолютно переносимым программам*? Кстати как из sizeof и CHAR\_BIT получается количество *десятичных* цифр? По 3 бита на цифру?

Переносимость -- это безусловно хорошо, но до известных пределов. При переходе на существенно другую архитектуру лучше опять почитать исходник (а может и заодно слегка переписать его) да и потестировать результаты переноса.

Comment: Есть организации, которые до сих пор COBOL используют -- это не значит, что это здравая идея, но у всех свой календарь (выбор языка (или его версии) от бизнеса в основном зависит, а не от технических достоинств).

Код может жить неожиданно долгое время. Я недавно изменял код, который старше меня. Следуя стандарту, мы повышаем вероятность, что наши внуки смогут работать с этим кодом. Даже откровенно вредные вещи, такие как `gets()` только недавно убрали. Пример с `printf(buf, ..` также вреден, если размер `buf` неверно указан.

Двоичный логарифм можно легко преобразовать в десятичный.

Answer (score 0):

*"Мне нужно сделать из int string."* -- [`str = to_string(i)`](http://ideone.com/XMjben). Чтобы попробовать на своей машине, [загрузи код по ссылке](http://ideone.com/plain/XMjben) и выполни команду: `g++ -std=c++11 ideone_XMjben.cpp && ./a.out`. Если слова "выполни команду", или сама команда не ясна -- задай отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот такой способ придумал.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char buf[40];
    int i = 123;

    itoa(i, buf, 10);

    string s;

    s += buf;

    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```